# Conv1D with kernel_size=1 vs Linear layer

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I'm working on very sparse vectors as input. I started working with simple `Linear` (dense/fully connected layers) and my network yielded pretty good results (let's take accuracy as my metric here, 95.8%).

I later tried to use a `Conv1d` with a `kernel_size=1` and a `MaxPool1d`, and this network works slightly better (96.4% accuracy).

*Question*: How are these two implementation different ? Shouldn't a `Conv1d` with a unit `kernel_size` do the same as a `Linear` layer?

I've tried multiple runs, the CNN always yields slightly better results.

Comment: Yes the `Conv1d` does the same assuming the implementations are correct (eg to run the CNN along the right axis vs the Linear broadcasted layer you need to call `inputs.transpose(1,2)`), probably all comes down to the `MaxPool1d`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`nn.Conv1d` with a kernel size of 1 and `nn.Linear` give essentially the same results. The only differences are the initialization procedure and how the operations are applied (which has some effect on the speed). Note that using a linear layer should be faster as it is implemented as a simple matrix multiplication (+ adding a broadcasted bias vector)

@RobinFrcd your answers are either different due to `MaxPool1d` or due to the different initialization procedure.

Here are a few experiments to prove my claims:

```py
def count_parameters(model):
    """Count the number of parameters in a model."""
    return sum([p.numel() for p in model.parameters()])

conv = torch.nn.Conv1d(8,32,1)
print(count_parameters(conv))
# 288

linear = torch.nn.Linear(8,32)
print(count_parameters(linear))
# 288

print(conv.weight.shape)
# torch.Size([32, 8, 1])
print(linear.weight.shape)
# torch.Size([32, 8])

# use same initialization
linear.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(conv.weight.squeeze(2))
linear.bias = torch.nn.Parameter(conv.bias)

tensor = torch.randn(128,256,8)
permuted_tensor = tensor.permute(0,2,1).clone().contiguous()

out_linear = linear(tensor)
print(out_linear.mean())
# tensor(0.0067, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)

out_conv = conv(permuted_tensor)
print(out_conv.mean())
# tensor(0.0067, grad_fn=<MeanBackward0>)
```

Speed test:

```py
%%timeit
_ = linear(tensor)
# 151 µs ± 297 ns per loop

%%timeit
_ = conv(permuted_tensor)
# 1.43 ms ± 6.33 µs per loop
```

As Hanchen's answer show, the results can differ very slightly due to numerical precision.

Answer (score 6):

I've encountered similar issues when working with 3d point clouds with models such as PointNet (CVPR'17). Therefore I've made a few more interpretations based on `Yann Dubois`'s answers. We first define a few utility functions and then report our findings:

```py
import torch, timeit, torch.nn as nn, matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def count_params(model):
    """Count the number of parameters in a module."""
    return sum([p.numel() for p in model.parameters()])


def compare_params(linear, conv1d):
    """Compare whether two modules have identical parameters."""
    return (linear.weight.detach().numpy() == conv1d.weight.detach().numpy().squeeze()).all() and \
           (linear.bias.detach().numpy() == conv1d.bias.detach().numpy()).all()


def compare_tensors(out_linear, out_conv1d):
    """Compare whether two tensors are identical."""
    return (out_linear.detach().numpy() == out_conv1d.permute(0, 2, 1).detach().numpy()).all()
```

1. With the same input and parameters, `nn.Conv1d` and `nn.Linear` are expected to produce same forward results arithmetically, but **experiments show that there are different**. We show this by plotting the histogram of the numerical differences. **Note that this numerical difference will increase as the network goes deep.**

```py
conv1d, linear = nn.Conv1d(8, 32, 1), nn.Linear(8, 32)

# same input tensor
tensor = torch.randn(128, 256, 8)
permuted_tensor = tensor.permute(0, 2, 1).clone().contiguous()

# same weights and bias
linear.weight = nn.Parameter(conv1d.weight.squeeze(2))
linear.bias = nn.Parameter(conv1d.bias)
print(compare_params(linear, conv1d))  # True

# check on the forward tensor
out_linear = linear(tensor)  # torch.Size([128, 256, 32])
out_conv1d = conv1d(permuted_tensor)  # torch.Size([128, 32, 256])
print(compare_tensors(out_linear, out_conv1d))  # False
plt.hist((out_linear.detach().numpy() - out_conv1d.permute(0, 2, 1).detach().numpy()).ravel())
```

[image: Fig.1 Histogram of forward tensor between nn.Conv1d and nn.Linear]

2. **Gradient updates in back propagation will also be numerically different.**

```py
target = torch.randn(out_linear.shape)
permuted_target = target.permute(0, 2, 1).clone().contiguous()

loss_linear = nn.MSELoss()(target, out_linear)
loss_linear.backward()
loss_conv1d = nn.MSELoss()(permuted_target, out_conv1d)
loss_conv1d.backward()

plt.hist((linear.weight.grad.detach().numpy() - 
    conv1d.weight.grad.permute(0, 2, 1).detach().numpy()).ravel())
```

[image: Fig.2 Histogram of backward tensor between nn.Conv1d and nn.Linear]

3. **Computing Speed on GPU.** `nn.Linear` is a bit faster than `nn.Conv1d`

```py
# test execution speed on CPUs
print(timeit.timeit("_ = linear(tensor)", number=10000, setup="from __main__ import tensor, linear"))
print(timeit.timeit("_ = conv1d(permuted_tensor)", number=10000, setup="from __main__ import conv1d, permuted_tensor"))

# change everything in *.cuda(), then test speed on GPUs
```

Comment: can you also confirm @RobinFrcd observation, that conv1d is better than linear? Thx

Comment: @arashjavanmard Yes, we found it is better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are different. I assume that you use the Pytorch API, and please read Pytorch's [Conv1d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#conv1d). To be honest, if you take the operator as a matrix product, Conv1d with kernel size=1 does generate the same results as Linear layer. However, it should be pointed out the operator used in Conv1d is a 2D [cross-correlation operator](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cross-correlation) which measures the similarity of two series. I think your dataset benefits from this mechanism.